# Inheriting a tuple as a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was just writing a program in which there is a class which inherits from a `tuple`. However, when I passed the argument as a list it still worked. Here is some of my code:

```
class Board(tuple):    
    def __init__(self, tup):
        print(type(tup))
        super().__init__()

board = Board([[Cell(False) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)])
print(type(board))
```

This program then outputs:

```
<class 'list'>
<class '__main__.Board'>
```

My question is as follows: why did Python let me pass a `list` as an argument when I said I would pass a `tuple`?

Comment: Where did you say you would pass a tuple?

Comment: I want to down vote the down voters on the question.  The question is well written.

Comment: Just like `tuple([])` is valid, so is `Board([])` (for any list, not just the empty list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, tup):
```

is just like other functions. And you have passed a list for the `tup` parameter. **There is no way you can restrict the type of the parameter in python.** Subclassing `tuple` just means that you are inheriting properties from the `tuple`, not that it can accept only tuples as parameters.

**Edit:** If you badly want a way to make sure that only tuples should be accepted, for some reason. You can raise exception like this

```
class Board(tuple):
    def __init__(self, tup):
        if not isinstance(tup, tuple):
            raise TypeError("Constrcutor argument to Board should be a tuple")
        super().__init__()

print Board([1, 2])
```

**Output**

```
TypeError: Constrcutor argument to Board should be a tuple
```

**Performance Comparison between `tuple` and `list`**

```
class Board(tuple):
    def __init__(self, tup):
        for i in tup:
            pass
myList, myTuple = range(10), tuple(xrange(10))

from timeit import timeit
print timeit("Board(myList)", "from __main__ import myList, Board", number = 1000000)
print timeit("Board(myTuple)", "from __main__ import myTuple, Board", number = 1000000)
```

**Output**

```
0.44806599617
0.413192987442
```

This clearly shows that passing a `list` as a parameter is very slightly slower than `tuple` and its almost negligible and they are almost equal in performance.

Comment: Would, then, my program be just as fast and efficient is I used a list as the argument?

Comment: @Lewis Technically `tuple` is slightly faster than `list` since they are immutable. But the gain will be close to negligible for small number of elements.

Comment: So is there a loss in speed because I pass a tuple? Would I be better off using adding `tuple()` to my statement like so: `board = Board(tuple([[Cell(False) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]))`?

Comment: @Lewis Please have a look at the performance comparison in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say anywhere that you expect `tup` to be a tuple.  You explicitly passed in a list, and arguments in Python are not type-checked.  You could restrict the type of the argument like this:

```
if type(tup) is not type(()):
    raise ValueError('Expected a tuple')
```

However, this isn't really necessary.  The Pythonic way of doing something like this is not to care about the type of object you have, but about whether it supports the operations you want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

The `tuple` describes the content of the board itself, not the content of any arguments passed to the initializer.

The arguments to the initializer don't necessarily represent the object itself; they could be things like parameters for a new object. Given that your function doesn't actually do anything with the input, you could pass literally anything.

Answer (score 0):

Both a list and a tuple are often used interchangeably as a sequence.

The distinction between a list and a tuple becomes important if you try to use it as a hash:

```
class Board(tuple):    
    def __init__(self, tup):
        print(type(tup))
        d={}
        d[tup]='test'          # this will fail with an unhashable type, like a list
        super().__init__()

b1=Board(tuple([1,2,3]))
b2=Board([1,2,3])
```

Prints:

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 8.py", line 9, in <module>
    b2=Board([1,2,3])
  File "Untitled 8.py", line 5, in __init__
    d[tup]='test'
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

There is usually no type checking in Python. It is an [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) language.

If you want a more 'formal' distinction and some formal checking of subclassing of types, consider using [collections.abc](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html) instead of base types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only `tuple` as parameter to `__init__` you can do following:

```
class Board(tuple):    
    def __init__(self, tup):
        if not isinstance(tup, tuple):
            raise Exception('Invalid type')
        super().__init__()
```

But it's **really** bad idea. It's not python way.

Comment: I don't know requirements, I see only original code - there is no passing to superclass.

Comment: Hm, there you are right, but I see no other use for this value than passing it up. The OP is a beginner and probably has forgotten this.

Answer (score -1):

Your code essentially does this.

```
>>> tuple([1,2,3])  # tuple() takes a list
(1, 2, 3)           # turns it into a tuple
```

Subclassing from `tuple` does not limit the class'es argument to `tuple`; it merely contains methods identical to `tuple` instances.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even do that -- `tup` is not passed anywhere except to `type()`.  It's effectively an unused argument when it comes to the state of `Board` objects.

Comment: It is passed to the init of the board.